# How to group input given in multiple arrays that look like [key1, "value1", key2, "value2", ...]?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I got this problem a few days ago and surprisingly it has created a lot of problems for my logical thinking.

We have three simple arrays:

```
var countries = [1, "DK", 2, "USA", 3, "Sweden"];
var languages = [2, "English", 1, "Danish", 3, "Swedish"];
var population = [3, 8000000, 1, 6000000, 2, 3000000000];
```

What the output should look like in console log is this:

```
// In USA people speak English and there live 300000000 people
// In DK people speak Danish and there live 6000000 people
// In Sweden people speak Swedish and there live 8000000 people
```

Now I was told it can be solved with a for loop, but I am getting stuck on how to get the position of the numbers and then saving those numbers so I can select them from the other two arrays.

It has to be dynamic, so as if I add more elements to the array, it automatically makes sentences like the three I mentioned above.

It is how I got it from the teacher, so the input array has to stay like that. Every number has a string after it in ascending order, and that's the pattern we have to figure out so it looks like the text I commented above.

Comment: As a first step, I would change the datastructure ...

Comment: @Sirko I guess, OP can't

Comment: @Hacketo Then this should be the first step of that "algorithm"

Comment: It is how I got it from the teacher, so it has to stay like that. Every number has a string after it in ascending order, and that's the pattern we have to figure out so it looks like the text i commented above.

Comment: This is like "how do I make cake from an egg, flour and sugar? what do you mean, break the egg? I am not allowed to change the structure!" :P Creating the new structure should be, as @Sirko says, the first step of your program, anything else is Bad Programming; he doesn't mean you should start your program with a nicer structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need to use more than one for loop.

Unless you want to change the structure of your data (see answer by georg), something like this should work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i+=2) {
  var countryId = countries[i];
  var countryName = countries[i+1];
  var countryLanguage, countryPopulation;
  for (var j = 0; j < languages.length; j+=2) {
    if (languages[j] == countryId) countryLanguage = languages[j+1];
  }
  for (var j = 0; j < population.length; j+=2) {
    if (population[j] == countryId) countryPopulation = population[j+1];
  }
  console.log("In " + countryName + " people speak " +
              countryLanguage + " and there live " +
              countryPopulation + " people");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the odd data structure. Convert it to something you can work with:

```js
var countries = [1, "DK", 2, "USA", 3, "Sweden"];
var languages = [2, "English", 1, "Danish", 3, "Swedish"];
var population = [3, 8000000, 1, 6000000, 2, 3000000000];

var data = {};

function addArray(key, ary) {
  
  for (var i = 0; i < ary.length; i += 2) {
    var j = ary[i];
    data[j] = data[j] || {};
    data[j][key] = ary[i + 1]; 
  }
}

addArray('country', countries);
addArray('language', languages);
addArray('population', population);

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(data,0,3));
```

It should be obvious how to get your output from this object.

Comment: Looks nice, but why hardcode the variable name `data` inside the `addArray()` function? Make it a parameter, and the function becomes reusable. Also, just a personal style preference, but I'd prefer `if (!data[j]) data[j] = {}` over `data[j] = data[j] || {}` (since, alas, JS won't let me write just `data[j] ||= {}`). And while we're at it, how about renaming the variable `j` to something slightly more meaningful, like `group`? And maybe pulling both values out of the array at the same time, as in `var group = ary[i], value = ary[i + 1]`, so that we can write `data[group][key] = value` later?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: thanks, there's surely a room for improvement, but since the OP doesn't seem to care, let's leave it as is for now.

Answer (score 1):

Though IE8 and below do not support Array.indexOf, you can try:

```
var countries = [1, "DK", 2, "USA", 3, "Sweden"];
var languages = [2, "English", 1, "Danish", 3, "Swedish"];
var population = [3, 8000000, 1, 6000000, 2, 3000000000];

var size = countries.length / 2;

for (var i = 1; i <= size; i++)
{
    var country = countries[countries.indexOf(i) + 1];
    var lang = languages[languages.indexOf(i) + 1];
    var pop = population[population.indexOf(i) + 1];

    console.log("In " + country + " people speak  " + lang + "  and there live  " + pop + "  people");
}
```

Comment: This solution uses only a loop as specified. The only thing I would change is that I would use the var keyword only once declaring country, lang, and pop outside of the loop with size to make it more efficient.

Comment: Just curious, why would it be more efficient?

Comment: most consider it trivial, but if you use a keyword more than it is needed you are you causing the program to do extra work. And doing more work than is required to complete a task is not efficient. Some would consider this micro optimizing, however I would disagree. Nothing is gained by not writing the code to be more efficient and in such cases I believe efficiency, no matter how small should be preferred. Note, also that you would be typing less to input it, which is a measurable increase in your own efficiency

Answer (score -1):

Change logic with 2D array like

```
var array = [["DK","English","8000000"],["USA","Danish","6000000"],["Sweden","Swedish","2000000"]];
```

From that you can easily find your value.

Answer (score -1):

```
console.log("In USA people speak " + languages[(languages.indexOf(countries[countries.indexOf("USA")-1])
+ 1)] + " and there live " + 
population[(population.indexOf(countries[countries.indexOf("USA")-1])+ 1)] + " people");
```

Note: This is a solution without manipulating the data first!
This works for the first one, others will be the same. Not sure if there is a better approach but this was my first instinct...